# In extjs charts, how do you hide the axis and axis labels?

Tags: extjs

I'm using extjs charts to display some data. In this data, the axis and axis labels are irrelevant - only the data trend is important. So I want to turn off the axises. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the *extraStyles* for the *x/yAxis*.

```
...,                
extraStyle: {
    xAxis:{showLabels:false},
    yAxis:{showLabels:false}
},
...
```

[More info can be found in the YUI charts API Docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/#basicstyles)

Comment: Wow, Shea Frederick answered my question! Your book has been a real help to me. Thanks!

Comment: I put this inside my items array and it didn't work, I didn't want to start a new question, because people will point to this as a duplicate, also forgive me, but the question was about ExtJS, how come you reference the YUI Charts docs? Are they basically the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: Pete, I'm not sure why this would not work for you - possibly your using the wrong version? In ExtJS 3.x (not 2.x, 1.x or 4.x) the included chart package is based on YUI charts, and uses the YUI charts Flash file, so this 'extraStyle' property can be taken directly from YUI charts documentation.